# Is a class I infra red laser range finder with range 30-40 metres possible?

Tags: laser, infrared

For our warehouse, we need to build a range finder for monitoring purposes. We have the following constraints:

- Use infra red lasers only
- Range should be at least 30 metres
- Only class 1 lasers permitted

We would be glad if you could tell us about the theoretical feasibility of such a range finder. If it is not possible than is there a work around ?

Also could you tell us how much is it going to cost ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: What's the minimum and maximum range that you'll be operating over?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy one from any sporting goods store that will work up to 500 yards.  So in theory and practice they are very feasable.  One issue that the commercial models have is that they do have a MINIMUM distance.  The one I have gas a min of 17 yards.

Answer (score 0):

Readily available sporting binoculars have range finders that work to 3000m

Cheap ones capable of 200m can be had for less than $300

Once you want a direct data interface the cost goes up quickly.

At short ranges under 10m clutter and spurious reflections matter.

Answer (score 0):

The range has more to do with the quality of the optics involved and the sensitivity and selectivity of the receiver. The quality of the algorithms in the ranger's microcontrollers could also be important (doesn't matter how good everything else is if the firmware can't interpret what it's sensors provide)

The power class only comes into play if the local atmospherics cause the beam to disperse or the beam is not focused properly, or if the ambient temperature (or the temperature of the target) is too high such that the receiver can't "pick out" the laser return reliably. In such case, a higher class laser would be 'brighter.'

Imagine the temperature being ambient light or glowing surfaces, the laser being a finely-focused flashlight, and the receiver being a contrast-detecting camera. You should be able to picture how these relate then?